# How to have add items in vuetify combobox and maintain v-model JSON structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify combobox that I set the v-model equal to some JSON array that has a property "EMAIL_ADDRESS" with an associated email address. If I use items that are already in this v-model the data format matches the original JSON array I set its value too:

```
[
  {
    "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testemail1@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testmail2@mail.com"
  }
]
```

If I add a item to the combobox which can happen since its a send email form. The array does not maintain the v-model structure of the original items array as shown here:

```
[
  {
    "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testemail1@mail.com"
  },
  "addedemail@mail.com",
  "addedemail2@gmail.com"
]
```

Is there any way to maintain the structure of the items array so it actually pushes the new value to that array?

```
<v-combobox label="To"                                                                          
            v-model="emailToModel"
            required
            multiple
            :items="emailTo"
            item-text="EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            class="ma-3"
            filled
            dense
            return-object
            hide-details="auto">
</v-combobox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve it by iterating `emailToModel` array and based on the type check you can convert the string into an object and then pushed into a `emailTo` array.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      emailToModel: [
        {
          "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testemail1@mail.com"
        },
        {
          "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testmail2@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      emailTo: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.emailTo = this.emailToModel
  },
  methods: {
    getUpdatedValue() {
      this.emailToModel = this.emailToModel.map(item => {
        if (typeof item !== 'object') {
          const newObj = {
            "EMAIL_ADDRESS": item
          };
          item = newObj
          this.emailTo.push(newObj);
        }
        return item;
      })
      console.log(this.emailToModel);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-combobox
            label="To"
            v-model="emailToModel"
            item-text="EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            :items="emailTo"
            multiple
            filled
            dense
            hide-details="auto"
            @change="getUpdatedValue"
          ></v-combobox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
  
  <pre>{{ emailToModel }}</pre>
</div>
```

**Update :** As per the author comment, creating a common generic method which will update the model and items value dynamically with irresepect to any number of combobox.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      emailToModel: [
        {
          "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testemail1@mail.com"
        },
        {
          "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testmail2@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      emailCcModel: [
        {
          "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "testemailCc1@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      emailTo: [],
      emailCc: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.emailTo = this.emailToModel
    this.emailCc = this.emailCcModel
  },
  methods: {
    getUpdatedValue(modelValue, comboboxItems) {
      this[modelValue] = this[modelValue].map(item => {
        if (typeof item !== 'object') {
          const newObj = {
            "EMAIL_ADDRESS": item
          };
          item = newObj
          this[comboboxItems].push(newObj);
        }
        return item;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-combobox
            label="To"
            v-model="emailToModel"
            item-text="EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            :items="emailTo"
            multiple
            filled
            dense
            hide-details="auto"
            @change="getUpdatedValue('emailToModel', 'emailTo')"
          ></v-combobox>
    </v-container>
    
     <v-container fluid>
          <v-combobox
            label="Cc"
            v-model="emailCcModel"
            item-text="EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            :items="emailCc"
            multiple
            filled
            dense
            hide-details="auto"
            @change="getUpdatedValue('emailCcModel', 'emailCc')"
          ></v-combobox>
    </v-container>   
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This pushes the new item correctly into the item array but the v-model still isnt of that form. The v-model also needs to be in this correct json form to work and have the "EMAIL_PROPERTY" for that new item.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the code snippet in the answer as per the comment. Hope it will help.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just curious, since this same issue happens with my To , Cc, and Bcc lines would it be poor practice to add the vmodel and item array as a parameter in the html/vuejs markup so I can use the function universally among those comboboxes? So getUpdatedValue(emailToModel, emailTo)?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 Yes best practice is to create a common method i.e `getUpdatedValue(emailToModel, emailTo)` and pass the model and items value dynamically from each combobox.

Comment: I selected your answer as the right answer but could you edit yours above to use this approach for completeness? Oddly enough when i replace the variables and do this it is updating the items array but not the v-model which is strange as your original code does work.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 That's fine. I added a comment.

Comment: added comment where? When i pass the v-model array and items array it does not seem to function as the code above. Can you adjust the code above to show how you would implement this universal method?

Comment: This is what I tried: getUpdatedValue(modelArr, itemArr) {
                modelArr = modelArr.map(item => {
                    if (typeof item !== 'object') {
                        const newObj = {
                            "EMAIL_ADDRESS": item
                        };
                        item = newObj
                        itemArr.push(newObj);
                    }
                    return item;
                })
            }

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 I updated the answer with the demo. Thanks !